# How to create a collection of iterators that advance through the same type in different ways

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm new to C++. I'd like to make a few iterators for my user-defined type. The typical C++ interface seems to be `myType.begin()` to create the iterator, `myType.end()` to create another iterator that represents one past the end point, `++iterator` to advance, and `*iterator` to access the current item.

But here are the problems I'm facing. First, there are multiple ways to iterate through my user-defined type. How would `myType.begin()` know which type to create? Currently, I'm making it such that the user creates the iterator themselves as passes `myType` into the constructor. It seems to work fine, and my only concern is that it doesn't appear to match C++ conventions.

Second, if `myType` doesn't know which iterator to create with `begin()`, then it certainly doesn't know what to produce for `end()`. Currently, I'm making it such that the iterator has an `isDone()` method. But again, this doesn't seem to match C++ conventions.

Thoughts? What's the conventional solution for creating a collection of iterators that advance through the same type in different ways?

As an aside: To get the iterator's current item... `*iterator` or `iterator.current()` ?

Comment: To answer your aside.  *iterator gets you the value stored at the iterator's location.  Can you give us more info on what your type looks like?

Comment: `begin` and `end` are not part of the Iterator concept itself. They're part of the (Iterator-)Range concept.

Comment: [Here's a description of the Iterator concept on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator) Note that there are several very useful refinements, such as ForwardIterator.

Comment: `.current()` and `.isDone()` are not associated in the (StdLib) C++ world with Iterators, but with Ranges. Unfortunately, there's not a broad consensus yet what a Range is, but the general idea is that a single iterator describes a single position within an ordered set, whereas a Range describes the ordered set itself (the order describes how to get to the next element).

Comment: @dyp The user-defined type is a tree structure of objects that represent the contents of a JSON file. Sometimes I want an iterator that will advance through only the top-level members. Sometimes I want an iterator that will advance through the 2-level members, sometimes limited to only those contained within a particular top-level member. It doesn't seem right for the tree to make its own iterator, since there could be several kinds, but having the user construct the iterator themselves seems contrary to most iterator interfaces I see.

Comment: `std::istream_iterator`, `std::back_inserter`, `std::reverse_iterator`, and probably a bunch of adapters in boost: There are plenty of iterator types that the user has to construct via a constructor, as opposed to `.begin()`. Also consider [`std::unordered_map::begin(int)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/begin2) which iterates over a single bucket of a hash table.